# Why Don't Browsers Interpret More Programming Languages?

Tags: javascript, php, browser

While there are a large number of programming languages, there are a small number of programming languages that browsers interpret. `<script>` tags have a type attribute that can be set to javascript or ecmascript. php may be embedded in html with a `<php [code] ?>` tag. Why aren't there similar mechanisms for embedding python/haskell/c/etc? They lack the browser environment (e.g. javascript's 'document' object and php's superglobals), but a similar environment could be constructed as a module in those languages. Many programming languages have cgi modules, so there is a precedent for this.

Comment: Err, PHP is not interpreted by the browser. It's a sever-side language, and there is *nothing* stopping you from using python/haskell/etc on the server. In fact, Python is a popular server-side language for use in websites.

Comment: Because you can't expect end-users to go install a fullblown Python, Haskell, Ruby, Brainf*ck, etc... package on their system to be able to support those languages.

Comment: Can you imagine the cross-browser support of in-browser php?

Comment: @JochemQuery - probably because it shows a complete lack of understanding of server and browser languages by suggesting that PHP is a browser language (and I didn't downvote)

Comment: Some browser are actually taking steps to make things like this possible somewhat, for example, https://developers.google.com/native-client/dev/?csw=1

Comment: If you so wish you can emulate many languages using JavaScript - e.g. python http://www.skulpt.org/ (however I don't recommend doing this for production websites).

Comment: *"Why Don't Browsers Interpret More Programming Languages?"* --- Take it up with the WWW consortium and the companies who bring us all the (free) Web browsers available on the open market. My take on this and to try and answer your question in the way I see it, is; if web browsers were able to handle all sorts of programming languages, the time involved in doing this would be astronomical and certainly not "economical"; we'd probably end up "paying" for a web browser. (and I too did NOT downvote, however I did vote to close as being "too broad").

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Most browsers interpret *one* programming language: JavaScript.

Internet Explorer also supports (or supported) VBScript. There is (or was years ago) a plugin that would add support for PerlScript to IE.

They don't support more because if one browser introduced support, then anyone writing code using that language would have it work on only one browser without being able to do anything they couldn't do in JavaScript. A decade ago, that wasn't a problem for Microsoft since they had dominance over the market and more so for corporate Intranets. Today, that has changed.

PHP is not interpreted by the browser, in the context of the WWW, it is processed on the server. You can use any language you like on the server, including Python, Haskell and C. Recently I've been using Perl (via Apache+FastCGI) and JavaScript (via Node.js).

Quite a lot of languages have means to allow you to embed the code directly in an HTML document (e.g. Perl's [Mason](https://metacpan.org/pod/HTML%3a%3aMason%3a%3aDevel)). However, it is generally preferred to separate the display logic from the other logic using a templating DSL (such as Template-Toolkit, Smarty or Handlebars).

Comment: So the "open" web has decided that browsers should not support any other language.

Comment: Free market forces. Sometimes great. Sometimes horrible. Mostly we just have to live with them.

Comment: Yes, but at least we needn't pretend it's all great.

Answer (score 5):

Browsers do interpret more languages through the use of plugins. Flash and Java come to mind. PHP is not browser interpreted, it is processed by the server, which sends pure HTML to the browser. Javascript is the one exception in that it works without a plugin.